# R: Assign a new value for whole column otherwise column stays as it is

Tags: r, dataframe, user-input

Im trying to "dynamically" change specific column values of different data.frames. For that Im using the `svDialogs` package to allow some minor value input.

The code i got so far is:

```
library(svDialogs)

a <- iris
b <- attitude

dfs <- c("a", "b")

for(df in dfs) {
  df.tmp <- get(df)
  for(i in 1:length(names(df.tmp))){
    df.tmp[i] <- dlgInput(sprintf('Enter new column value for "%s" and press ok. Click Abort to change nothing', names(df.tmp)[i]), Sys.info()["n"])$res
  } 
  assign(df, df.tmp)
}
```

That piece of code assigns the entered number/string to the whole column displayed. But the problem is when clicking Abort (in the pop up dialog) it assigns `NA` to the columns. Well what i would need is that when clicking abort that the column stays how it is. How could i archive something like that? I tried some different `else` statement but i did not succeed. Anyone any ideas. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
So if my column looks like that before:

```
A    B   C
5    6   10
2    3   8
car  bus car
7    77  8
```

Then the pop up questions appear:
Enter new column value for "A" and press ok. Click Abort to change nothing.
=> Click

> Abort

Enter new column value for "B" and press ok. Click Abort to change nothing.
=> I write Test and click

> O.K

Enter new column value for "C" and press ok. Click Abort to change nothing.
=> Click

> Abort

Then the resulting data.frame looks like the following:

```
A    Test C
5    6    10
2    3    8
car  bus  car
7    77   8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, I am capturing the user input into a variable and checking if it's not empty. When I ran the example, I entered 1, 2, 3, 4 and then pressed Cancel two times and continued entering integers from 8 to 14.

```
library(svDialogs)

a <- iris
b <- attitude

dfs <- c("a", "b")

for(df in dfs) {
  df.tmp <- get(df)
  for(i in 1:length(names(df.tmp))){
    ui <- dlgInput(sprintf('Enter new column value for "%s" and press ok. Click Abort to change nothing', names(df.tmp)[i]), default = "", Sys.info()["n"])$res

    if (length(ui) == 0) {
      next
    } else {
      df.tmp[i] <- ui
    }
  } 
  assign(df, df.tmp)
}
```

Here's the result.

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            1           2            3           4  setosa
2            1           2            3           4  setosa
3            1           2            3           4  setosa
4            1           2            3           4  setosa
5            1           2            3           4  setosa
6            1           2            3           4  setosa
> head(b)
  rating complaints privileges learning raises critical advance
1     43          8          9       11     12       13      14
2     63          8          9       11     12       13      14
3     71          8          9       11     12       13      14
4     61          8          9       11     12       13      14
5     81          8          9       11     12       13      14
6     43          8          9       11     12       13      14
```

Comment: O.k. perhaps my question was a bit confusing. What Im trying to do is to overwrite a whole column with the (one) value i enter in the pop up dialog. Not changing the column names. That also pretty much works. But if i click abort `NA` is written to the whole column but i would like it then to change nothing for that asked column. I hope my question becomes a bit clearer now. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: Not just better, but simply perfect! Now i have to take my time to go thought it and grasp the why. Thank you very much!
Edit: O.k your answer is even greater then i thought because it is fast to understand and well (if you know how) quite easy.